# How to use Mathematica to find the coordinates of 7 points?

Tags: programming, geometry, computational-geometry, vector, algorithm

Could anyone please help me with using Mathematica to find the coordinates of 7 equally spaced points on the unit sphere $S^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try `Graphics3D[Point[SpherePoints[20]]]`.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Thank you for your comment, but my question is about n-dimensional sphere.

Comment: Do you mean that the distance between all pairs of points is the same? Is that possible?